# Fisher information matrix for comparing two treatments

Tags: maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution, independence, fisher-information

This is an exercise from Larry Wasserman's book "[All of Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387402721)". Unfortunately, there is no solution online.

The exercise is the following (quoting from Wasserman's book):

> $n_1$ people are given treatment $1$ and $n_2$ people are given treatment $2$. Let $X_1$ be the number of people on treatment $1$ who respond favourably to the treatment and $X_2$ be the number of people on treatment $2$ who respond favourably. Assume $X_1 \sim Binomial(n_1,p_1)$ and $X_2 \sim Binomial(n_2, p_2)$. Let $\psi := p_1-p_2$.

First task was to find the MLE of $\psi$ which is just the $\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2$ where $\hat{p}_i$ is the MLE of $p_i$ by functional invariance of the MLE. The second task is to find the Fisher information matrix $I(p_1, p_2)$, where the generally $(i,j)$ entry $H_{i,j}$ is defined as the expectation of

$$ H_{i,j}=\frac{\partial^2 l_n}{\partial \theta_i\partial \theta_j}$$

and $l_n := \sum_{i = 1}^n \log{f(X_i;\theta)}$. In our case $\theta_1 = p_1$ and $\theta_2 = p_2$, i.e. the Fisher information matrix is a $2\times 2$ matrix. I'm puzzled about the different $n$. Is in this case $n=2$ for $X_1$ and $X_2$ or is it $n=n_1+n_2$? I think it is $2$, is this correct?

So lets calculate the matrix entries. For this note

$$l_n = \sum_{i=1}^2\log{\binom{n_i}{x_i}p_i^{x_i}(1-p_i)^{n_i-x_i}}$$

since we will take partial derivative wrt to $p_i$ we can forget about the binomial coefficient, i.e.

$$l_n = \sum_{i=1}^2x_i\log{p_i}+(n_i-x_i)\log{(1-p_i)}$$

So we get

$$H_{ii}=-\frac{x_i}{p_i^2}+\frac{n_i-x_i}{(1-p_i)^2}$$
and
$$H_{ij}=H_{ji}=\frac{x_i}{p_i}-\frac{n_i-x_i}{1-p_i}+\frac{x_j}{p_j}-\frac{n_j-x_j}{1-p_j}$$

So taking expectation we get

$$E_{p_ip_i}[H_{ii}]=-\frac{n_ip_i}{p_i^2}+\frac{n_i-n_ip_i}{(1-p_i)^2}=-\frac{n_i}{p_i}+\frac{n_i}{1-p_i}$$
and
$$E_{p_ip_j}[H_{ij}]=E_{p_ip_j}[H_{ji}]=0$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Are $N_1$ and $N_2$ (abuse of notation; using the sample size to denote the sample) independently sampled, and is any part of $N_1$ ($N_2$) used to compute $\hat{p}_2$ ($\hat{p}_1$)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm puzzled about the different n. Is in this case n=2 for X1 and X2
>   or is it n=n1+n2? I think it is 2, is this correct?

Your data is made of $(x_1,x_2)$ which is a single observation of a random vector $(X_1,X_2)$ where
$$X_1\sim\mathcal{B}(n_1,p_1)\qquad X_2\sim\mathcal{B}(n_2,p_2)$$
with $X_1$ independent from $X_2$. Hence $n=1$.

> $$H_{ii}=-\frac{x_i}{p_i^2}+\frac{n_i-x_i}{(1-p_i)^2}$$

This is not correct: Since
$$l_n = x_1\log{p_1}+(n_1-x_1)\log{(1-p_1)}+x_2\log{p_2}+(n_2-x_2)\log{(1-p_2)}$$
the second derivative $$H_{11}=\dfrac{\partial^2 l_n}{\partial p_1^2}$$
is given by
$$H_{11}=\dfrac{\partial^2 l_n}{\partial p_1^2}=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial p_1} \left\{\dfrac{x_1}{p_1} - \dfrac{n_1-x_1}{1-p_1}\right\}=-\dfrac{x_1}{p_1}^2-\dfrac{n_1-x_1}{(1-p_1)^2}$$
with expectation
$$\mathbb{E}[H_{11}]= -\dfrac{\mathbb{E}[x_1]}{p_1^2}-\dfrac{\mathbb{E}[n_1-x_1]}{(1-p_1)^2}=-\dfrac{n_1}{p_1}-\dfrac{n_1}{1-p_1}$$

> $$H_{ij}=H_{ji}=\frac{x_i}{p_i}-\frac{n_i-x_i}{1-p_i}+\frac{x_j}{p_j}-\frac{n_j-x_j}{1-p_j}$$

This is not correct: Since
$$l_n = x_1\log{p_1}+(n_1-x_1)\log{(1-p_1)}+x_2\log{p_2}+(n_2-x_2)\log{(1-p_2)}$$
the second derivative $$H_{12}=\dfrac{\partial^2 l_n}{\partial p_1\partial p_2}$$
is given by
$$H_{12}=\dfrac{\partial^2 l_n}{\partial p_1\partial p_2}=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial p_1} \left\{\dfrac{x_2}{p_2} - \dfrac{n_2-x_2}{1-p_2}\right\}=0$$
since the term between braces does not depend on $p_1$. That the expectation of $H_{12}=H_{21}$ is indeed zero is coherent with the fact that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

Comment: Thanks, yes there was the sign error. Many thanks for your answer.